# Read TIFF file in AIR?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, graphics, air

Is there any way to read a `TIFF` file using `AIR`? Looks like `Flash` doesn't have native support for TIFF format. Are there any libraries available?

Comment: well, TIFF is maintained by Adobe. Interesting how they don't support it in their own product :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a working decoder (uncompressed files only): http://www.ctyeung.com/AIR/index.html

Answer (score 1):

According to [this](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7d66.html), TIFF **is** supported by Adobe Flash Player and Adobe AIR, together with BMP, GIF, JPG, and PNG.

**edit:**
FTA:

> The drawback with the TIFF format is that because of the many different varieties of TIFF, there is no single reader that can handle every version. In addition, no web browsers currently support the format.

**edit2:**
It appears that dynamic loading of TIFF is not possible. I couldn't find any third-party library to do so.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer, but flash.display.Loader throws an exception when trying to open a TIFF file, and the documentation says it only supports JPEG and PNG. Maybe there is some other way?..

Comment: You're right, it only supports JPG, PNG, and GIF. I'll try to look for a way to use TIFF ...

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://blog.kevinhoyt.org/2009/03/10/actionscript-3-tiff-encoder/) is an open source encode project, and according the author that decode future has been working on.

Comment: Thanks, I found this one too - but unfortunately encoding is pretty easy compared to decoding, and I need decoding. Thanks anyway.